# Drawing on WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, silverlight, drawing, writeablebitmap, stroke

I have a WriteableBitmap and would like the user to be able to draw over it as if it was an InkPresenter control. What is the best way to go about doing this in realtime? Using WriteableBitmap.Pixels, I'm able to access each pixel, but when I try to edit them during the MouseMove event, it seems very slow, and only changes one pixel at a time. Are there any libraries or methods to help make this process easier? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. I was using that but it only seems to allow a 1-pixel wide line. It has some nice features, but all I need is a paint brush of arbitrary size.